# Why my chi-squared test and logistic regression gave different results

Tags: r, logistic-regression, chi-squared

I had a dataset that contain columns "leaver (binary variable)", "target position (categorical)", "target regions (categorical )" etc. and I am trying to discover which factors can significantly impact on "leaver" (eg. whether this person/row is likely to leave the firm)

```
chisq.test(EBRD_leaver$target_ebrd_region, EBRD_leaver$leaver)


set.seed(1)
#Use 70% of dataset as training set and remaining 30% as testing set
sample<-sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), nrow(EBRD_leaver), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7,0.3))
train <- EBRD_leaver[sample,]
test <- EBRD_leaver[!sample,]

#fit logistic regression model
model4 <- glm(leaver~target_group, family="binomial", data=train)
#disable scientific notation for model summary
options(scipen=999)

#view model summary
summary(model4)
```

These two models are examining the same and only one factor "target_region". Why the results are so different (chi-squared said it's significant but glm said not at all)

Thanks for any help

Comment: You use the data `train` for the `glm` but the data `EBRD_leaver` for he `chisq.test`.(If this is just a typo in your question, then to get an answer you will need to al least add the summary results of each method, and even better a reproducible example).

Comment: Have you tried running `glm` with the full `EBRD_leaver` data? When testing a hypothesis you don't normally split into `train` and `test` datasets.